# Emojin conver to unicode

Tags: c#, asp.net, emoji

> Hi, I have web application and also android application. When I save emoji in android I can show emoji in asp.net listview. But when I open browser in phone and save emoji its saved as (  ---->>> ??????) in database (MSSQL). How can I save emoji as like  ---->>> \uD83D\uDE02\uD83D\uDE03\uD83D\uDE04\uD83D\uDE04.
>
> I want to when I entered emoji (), its save as Unicode (\uD83D\uDE02\uD83D\uDE03\uD83D\uDE04) in asp.net.

Thanks.

Comment: Either change the database collation to support unicode characters (if at all possible) or encode the unicode characters with ther hex values before you store them in the database and convert them back when you load them.

Comment: But I also use services for android application. I must save as Unicode .How can I convert    ---->>> \uD83D\uDE02\uD83D\uDE03\uD83D\uDE04\uD83D\uDE04 before store database in asp.net.